# Trouble understanding pop() when implementing Queue using Stacks

Tags: python, recursion, stack, queue

This is a leetcode question. Full question here: https://leetcode.com/problems/implement-queue-using-stacks/solution/

Here is the full solution.

```
class MyQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s1 = []
        self.s2 = []

    def push(self, x):
        #Time complexity = O(1)
        #Space complexity = O(1)

        self.s1.append(x)

    def pop(self):
        #Time complexity = O(n)
        #Space complexity = O(n)
        self.peek()
        return self.s2.pop()

    def peek(self):
        #Time complexity = O(1)
        #space complexity = O(1)

        if self.s2 == []: #if s2 is empty
            while self.s1 != []: #while s1 is not empty
                self.s2.append(self.s1.pop()) #s2 takes in all the s1 values | i don't understand this line???
        return self.s2[-1]        

    def empty(self):
        #Time complexity = O(1)
        #Space complexity = O(1)
        return self.s1 == [] and self.s2 == []
```

The code works fine but I don't understand this specific line:

```
self.s2.append(self.s1.pop())
```

this is from this function:

```
    def peek(self):

        if self.s2 == []: #if s2 is empty
            while self.s1 != []: #while s1 is not empty
                self.s2.append(self.s1.pop()) #s2 takes in all the s1 values
        return self.s2[-1]
```

I am trying to follow the code but don't understand how `self.s1.pop()` actually returns anything?

Moreover, what's the difference in functionality of `self.s1.pop()` vs `self.pop()`

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function pop() is suppose to remove the top element from the stack and at the same time return that removed value, upon return its going to put whatever was returned and deleted from top of s1 stack into the top of s2 stack.

Comment: Thank you! so stupid of me to completely forget about the built-in python pop function for lists.. thanks!

Comment: Its okay! we all get confused even on the simplest problems sometimes. Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am sorry guys. I was so deep into looking into the actual the self defined pop functions that I completely forgot about the python built in pop() function for the lists! Solved!